# Ordering-by the same column in a table with different sort order based on a condition using querybuilder

Tags: sql, doctrine, query-builder, shopware

I have table, where i need to check a condition while running a select statement on this table, based on the condition i need to change the ordering condition.
How to achieve this using query builder (Doctrine).
example: table name -> product

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>pid</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>instock</th>
    <th>laststock</th> 
    <th>price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>234</td> 
    <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td> 
    <td>101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>345</td> 
    <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td> 
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>567</td> 
    <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td> 
    <td>103</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>678</td> 
    <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td> 
    <td>104</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>123</td> 
    <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td> 
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

so in this table, i need to first check instock value if it is greater than zero i need to order it in DESC order (instock column). else i need to order in ASC order(instock column). How to do this using query builder?

I need output like this

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>pid</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>instock</th>
<th>laststock</th>
<th>price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>one</td>
<td>123</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>four</td>
<td>567</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>103</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>two</td>
<td>234</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>101</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>three</td>
<td>345</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>102</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>five</td>
<td>678</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>104</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What i tried is

```
$query->addOrderBy(($query->expr()->neq('variant.instock', 0)), 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy(($query->expr()->eq('variant.instock', 0)) , 'ASC');
```

Eventually this would call SQL query like this below

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY instock <> 0 DESC, instock = 0 ASC
```

and give output like this

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>pid</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>instock</th>
<th>laststock</th>
<th>price</th>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>two</td>
<td>234</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>101</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>four</td>
<td>567</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>103</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>one</td>
<td>123</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>three</td>
<td>345</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>102</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>five</td>
<td>678</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>104</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please, reply if the table is not easy to read, i post the images of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql code can be like below

```
  SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY case when instock = 0 then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: yeah, but i need to do the changes in querybuilder. How to add the "CASE" in querybuilder?